# CLLocationManager, MKReverseGeocoder, cleaning up memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocation, mkreversegeocoder

In the More iPhone 3 development book, after the author is done with the *locationManager* delegate method of getting updates, he puts this at the end of that method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    // some code here

    manager.delegate = nil;
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [manager autorelease];    
}
```

And similarly, in the *MKReverseGeocoder* delegate methods, when he's done he does this:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {

    //some code here

    geocoder.delegate = nil;
    [geocoder autorelease];
}
```

Why do you need to do that in order to clean up memory?  I thought the rule was if you alloc/init it, you need to release it.  Why does he add the locationManager and geocoder to the autorelease pool?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is done to avoid calling the delegate methods

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

or

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
```

when you dealloc the object that responds to those `CLLocationManager/MKReverseGeocoder` protocols